# Regex a: b c d a:b

Tags: python, regex

I currently have the regex `'([^: ]+):([^ ]+)?'`, which when given a string like `This is a correct:test msg: a b c bool:y` returns `[('correct', 'test'), ('msg', ''), ('bool', 'y')]` (using pythons `re.findall`).

I actually want it to return something like `[('correct', 'test'), ('msg', 'a b c'), ('bool', 'y')]`. How do I force regex to look inside the second chunk, and see if theres a `:` in it?

Comment: Why `[('correct', 'test), ('msg', 'a b c'), ('bool', 'y')]` and not `[('correct', 'test'), ('msg', 'a'), ('b c bool', y')]`?  That is, how should the regex know you want the one and not the other?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do a negative lookahead to make sure the word you're consuming doesn't belong in the 1st position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) on the second part, e.g.

```
'([^ :]+): *(.+?)?(?:(?= [^ ]+:)|$)'
```